# Show that $\beta $ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have started reading **field theory**.

Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$ and let $\alpha,\beta\in E$.Suppose that $\alpha $ is transcendental over $F$ but algebraic over $F(\beta)$.

Show that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.

Since $\alpha$ is  algebraic over $F(\beta)\implies \exists p(x)\neq 0$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$ .So $p(x)$ must be a polynomial over $F(\beta)$ and not over $F$.

But these facts are taking me nowhere near the solution.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $p$ and write it as
$$
p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n
$$
where each $a_i \in F(\beta)$ is of the form
$$
a_i = \frac{q_i(\beta)}{r_i(\beta)}
$$
where $q_i,r_i \in F[x]$ are polynomials. Hence if $r := \prod r_i$, then
$$
r(\beta)[\tilde{q_o}(\beta) + \tilde{q_1}(\beta)\alpha + \ldots + \tilde{q_n}(\beta)\alpha^n] = 0
$$
for some polynomials $\tilde{q_1}, \ldots, \tilde{q_n} \in F[x]$. Collecting like terms, one can write this in the form
$$
b_0 + b_1\beta + \cdots +  b_m\beta^m = 0
$$
where each $b_i$ is a polynomial expression in $\alpha$. This proves that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$

Comment: Just want to ask that if $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$, then $r_i(\beta)=1$ right? And also I wonder that where the fact "$\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$" is applied in the proof.

Comment: @AlanWang This answer might need clarification. " $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$ " is needed to show that the polynomial $b_0 + \dots + b_m x^m$ is non-zero. First, it implies the existence of $a_i = \frac{q_i(\beta)}{r_i(\beta)}$ with one of $q_i$ or $r_i$ being non-constant polynomials. Also, for a polynomial like $\alpha^i m(x)$, each of its nonzero monomial term will not be eliminated by $\alpha^j s(x)$ with $j \neq i$; otherwise, $\alpha$ will be algebraic over $F$.

Comment: I think that you need to also show that ${b_i}$ aren't zero. You can do that by assuming they are all zero, and reaching a polynomial of order $n-1$ with root on $\alpha$, given that we choose $p(x)$ to be the minimal polynomial - contradiction.